# Reuse Step Definitions with Yadda and Protractor, iterate through required files

Tags: javascript, protractor, bdd, yadda

I'm new to JavaScript and I've recently started writing automated tests with Protractor and Yadda so that I can use Gherkin.  However I've just found that step definitions don't appear to be reusable, i.e. if I run the feature

```
testMyWebAppRocks.feature
```

it will use the steps defined in

```
testMyWebAppRocks.steps.js
```

However, it may be that a several of the same steps from that feature file, such as

```
    Given I am on the homepage
```

which will appear in another feature file, such as

```
testThisParticularPartOfMyWebAppRocks.feature
```

and requires the steps to be rewritten in the step definition that corresponds to that feature.  Obviously this is not ideal, doesn't fit with DRY and for a one page web app that is quite complex could require the same steps for many features.

So, is there a way to load all of the step definitions into a library and run the features against that library?  What is the best practice when doing this sort of thing?

Obviously I don'want to have to stuff all of my scenarios into one unmanageable feature file, and likewise with the step definitions.  I also don't want to have to keep repeating the same code.

**UPDATE**

OK, so I've figured out a way around this, by joining my libraries together

```
var library = englishLibrary.library();
var firstSteps = require('./steps/first-steps')(library);
var secondSteps = require('./steps/second-steps')(firstSteps);
var yadda = Yadda.createInstance(secondSteps);
```

My problem now is that this will soon get quite ugly, Is it possible to do this in a loop?  If I could use glob then I wouldn't need to know about the actual step-definitions name, but I really don't know JavaScript well enough to quite know where to start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular reason why you can't.

As far as JS is concerned, you can basically pass any value anywhere, this includes passing things to `require` calls.

Whether or not this is a 'good' structure is kind of another question altogether.

It might be helpful for you to note that what you're actually passing to the `given` `when` etc. method calls are functions -
If you find yourself passing the same function over and over again, why not just break the function definitions out into a `./lib/common_test_functions` library?

Rather than:

```
Yadda.localisation.English.library()
.given('I am on the homepage', function() {
    // Code goes here
});
```

Perhaps:

```
var testUtils = require('./lib/common_test_functions.js')
Yadda.localisation.English.library()
.given('I am on the homepage',testUtils.verifyHomePage)
```

There is nothing saying you -have- to pass anonymous functions as callbacks - You can define the functions anywhere you want to, and pass them in as you need them.

You could even do something like :

```
function myGivenWrapper(yaddaInstance,testText,testFunction){
    yaddaTestLib.given(testText,testFunction)
}
var yadda = Yadda.localisation.English.library()
myGivenWrapper(yadda,testUtils.homepage.givenText,testUtils.homepage.test)
```

JS gives you a lot of expressive power to just kind of shuffle function calls around however you want to - If someone's lib doesn't seem to have architected things in a way that makes sense for your use case, you can always write wrapper functions and implement a "better" interface.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this...

```
var libraries = [
    require('./lib/hospital-library'),
    require('./lib/patient-library'),
    require('./lib/discharge-library')
];

var yadda = Yadda.createInstance(libraries);
```